# Phonegap ajax has no reponse text?

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf&minus;8" type="text/javascript">
        $.support.cors = true;
        function connect(e) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.0.100/xxx/index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            error: function(jqXHR,text_status,strError) {
              alert("no connection");
            },
            timeout: 60000,
            success: function(data) {
              alert("success");
              $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
          });     
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <center><b>Bikes or Cars</b></center>
    <center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="cars" /></center>
    <center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="bikes" /></center>
    <center><b>Results</b></center>
    <ul id="result"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
$choice =$_POST["button"];
$cars = array("Honde", "BMW" , "Ferrari");
$bikes = array("Ducaite", "Royal Enfield" , "Harley Davidson");
if($choice == "cars") print json_encode($cars);
else print json_encode($bikes);
?>
```

The problem is when I run this code from my google chrome the response is:

```
"[\"Ducaite\",\"Royal Enfield\",\"Harley Davidson\"]"
```

But when I try to run it from my android device, I get a response of an empty string or null response. I dont now why, 
I already added

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in my `config.xml` and in my manifest is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: You will need to enable CORS on your server as well.

Comment: what cors should i add ? do you have sample ?